# How to create background service through AlarmManager with codename one native interface?

Tags: java, android, codenameone, native-code, android-looper

First time I try native interface with Codename one for android. I try below code to get the data store on server in the background after a particular time, even when the application is not running. I am not considering if data service / wifi is enabled or not. To get this done, I create a native implementation through Codename one. After google so much and trying too many methods still getting same error `Looper.prepare();` to call in the handler. Code of one of my tries through `service` is below. I am not android programmer so, please don't consider me as an expert in android.

Code in native Impl :

```
public class NativeCallImpl {

public void setNative(String param) {
    implCall ic = new implCall();
    ic.Native(param);
}

public boolean isSupported() {
    return true;
}
}
```

impl call class :

```
class implCall extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.

}

public void Native(String param) {
    try {
        Toast.makeText(this, param, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), UploadData.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime(), 10000, pendingIntent);
        //startService(intent);   

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

}
}
```

Class called in Intent :

```
public class UploadData extends Service {

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    //return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    try {

        String data = URLEncoder.encode("mobileNumber", "UTF-8") + "="
                + URLEncoder.encode(user.user.getMobileNumber(), "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("EventName", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("na", "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("Status", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("auto", "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("Latitude", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("lat", "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("Longitude", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("long", "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("Address", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("na", "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("imageCode", "UTF-8")
                + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("na", "UTF-8");

        URL url = new URL("http://example.com/appFiles/checkInOut/checkInOut.php");

        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //Toast.makeText(null, ex.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

}
```

Error Message :

[image]

Comment: you can't do this:   implCall ic = new implCall(); you have to declare that method in a class not in a activity , an activity can't be initialize that way

Comment: Why aren't you using the codenameone local notifications API - http://www.codenameone.com/blog/local-notifications.html. it allows you to schedule a task to be executed at a future time in the background (it is implemented using AlarmManager )

Answer (score 1):

As @chen mentioned you should use the [builtin local notifications](http://www.codenameone.com/blog/local-notifications.html) and don't need native code for this.

This will work for iOS too so it's far better. The exception at hand is called because you are using the Codename One thread instead of the Android thread you need to wrap your call with `runOnUiThread` from the activity.

Comment: local notification method can work in background even when **application is not running** and can this method send data through connection request to server ? (if yes then through `LocalNotificationCallback` you mean to say). The question because of this line : `They are useful for communicating information to the user while the **app is running in the background**, since they manifest themselves as pop-up notifications on supported devices.`

Comment: It will communicate data to the user when the app isn't running at all. Notice that they won't trigger a network connection unless the user clicks on them. That's the way this works for iOS and Android aligns the behavior with iOS for portability.